# Multiprocess Pool is Running but no result is coming

Tags: python, parallel-processing, tiff, pool

I am Using Big-Fish Library and trying to run parallel the tiff files with Multiprocessing .pool but The code is running for a long time but no result is coming out

```
import os
import numpy as np
import bigfish
import bigfish.stack as stack
import bigfish.detection as detection
import bigfish.multistack as multistack
import bigfish.plot as plot
import time
import bigfish
import psutil
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool

folder = 'path'
def process_tiff(file):
  # Load the TIFF file using BigFish
  rna = stack.read_image(file)
  spots, threshold = detection.detect_spots(
        images=rna,
        return_threshold=True,
        voxel_size=(300, 103, 103),
        spot_radius=(350, 150, 150))
  df = pd.DataFrame(spots, columns=["z", "y", "x"])
  csv_file = file.replace('.tiff', '.csv')
  a= df.to_csv(folder+csv_file, index=False)
  print(f'done {a}')

file =[f for f in os.listdir(folder) if f.endswith('.tiff')]
def main():    
    p = Pool(12)
    p.map(process_tiff, file)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am expecting the code should run parallely

Comment: Did you try adding in `print` statements before each file is processed to see if it at least starts? Did you try putting just one CPU in the pool? Didyou check your memory consumption?

Comment: Hi I did , but no result is printing just running continuously with out any output@MarkSetchell

Comment: Please add `print('main')` as the first line of `main()` and `print(file)` as the first line of `process_tiff()` and start with `python -u YOURSCRIPT.PY`

Comment: @MarkSetchell , Sorry no luck, it is not printing or saving any result

Comment: Mmmm, exactly **how** are you starting it and what OS are you using? If Windows, did you use the `freeze_support()` thing? https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20freeze_support#multiprocessing.freeze_support

Comment: please let me check that

Comment: @MarkSetchell Heyy, I tried it did not worked, can you please tell me is there any alternative way i can do it?